# How to create a bootstrap table with hidden child rows?

Tags: nested, bootstrap-table

I have come accross [this bootply example](https://www.bootply.com/GGAMvot45f#), but I am not able to replicate it anywhere. The page does not display any javascript, be it imported files or direct code on the javascript section, and so the best I can get is a table that does not work.

Aside from this bootply example I could not find any other code online that performs the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the latest minified bootstrap.js, if not include 
`<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`and try again. I hope this helps